# Grep specific data from a string

Tags: shell-script, grep, string, data

Here is the data:

```
Valid from: Fri Nov 24 12:11:28 EST 2017 until: Sun Nov 24 12:11:28 EST 2019
Valid from: Fri Feb 24 13:21:19 EST 2017 until: Thu Feb 24 13:31:19 EST 2022
Valid from: Tue Dec 20 12:01:19 EST 2016 until: Fri Dec 20 12:11:17 EST 2041
```

I want to extract only data which is written after 'until:' word.

For example I should get only `Sun Nov 24 12:11:28 EST 2019`.

Comment: Does the solution require `grep`, or are you just suggesting that `grep` might be a solution to your *real question*, which is "[how do I] return specific data from [a] string?"

Comment: The title references "Grep" but there's no reason why the grep command should be involved in this at all, the way it's presented. @GAD3R is correct; this is a dupe.  It has nothing to do with returning specific lines and everything to do with throwing away everything before a specific pattern of characters, which the other question already answers perfectly.

Comment: you want only the first line or the text after until on each lines? Because you said: `I should get only Sun Nov 24 12:11:28 EST 2019.` It's not clear if it's only the 1st line example or the result of the whole.

Answer (score 8):

Try also

```
awk '{sub (/^.*until: /, "")} 1' file
Sun Nov 24 12:11:28 EST 2019
Thu Feb 24 13:31:19 EST 2022
Fri Dec 20 12:11:17 EST 2041
```

or even shorter

```
sed 's/^.*until: //' file
Sun Nov 24 12:11:28 EST 2019
Thu Feb 24 13:31:19 EST 2022
Fri Dec 20 12:11:17 EST 2041
```

Comment: can also use "until: " as the field separator and print the 2nd field: `awk -F 'until: ' '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 6):

With GNU grep

```
echo "$string" | grep -oP 'until: \K.*'
```

That matches the word "until: ", then the `\K` forgets about everything that was just matched, then the `.*` can match everything after that.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about `\K`. Until now I always used lookbehinds, but this saves three characters ;-)

Comment: one of the drawbacks of lookbehinds is that the patterns have to have a fixed width. That restriction does not apply with `\K`

Answer (score 3):

By setting the `awk` delimiter to `"until:"` you can get the subsequent string while this text exist on your string. `awk -F'until:' '{print $2}'`

```
echo "Valid from: Fri Nov 24 12:11:28 EST 2017 until: Sun Nov 24 12:11:28 EST 2019" | awk -F'until:' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep -o 'until: [^V]*' file | cut -d ':' -f 2-`

Comment: why `[^V]`  and not just `.` ?

Comment: first sample wasn't split for lines, So I was grepping until next 'V' in 'Valid' word. I Agree, That now it loooks weered .

Answer (score 2):

If format will always be the same you can also try :

```
cut -d':' -f 5- /path-to-file
```